# Ruby: Right way to do optimistic locking?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, locking

Context: Product is getting updated by multiple threads. So it leads the race condition. So I am using optimistic locking because it is frequently not updated. For latest update state of the product is determined by `updated_at` attribute.

For example, Prod (id=1) is updated at t1 on the machine:1. Same product(id=1) is updated at t2 on the machine:2. Now the state of Prod (id=1) on the machine:1 is stale.

Approach To determine stale: I will compare the value of `updated_at` on the machine with the store value of `updated_at`in the database value.

My main concern is setting the value of `@original_updated_at`. Should I use `attr_writer :original_updated_at`. Is this right way do optimistic locking.

```
attr_accessor : :original_updated_at
  def original_updated_at
    @original_updated_at || updated_at.to_f
  end


  def stale_object?
    if updated_at.to_f > original_updated_at.to_f
      @original_updated_at = nil
      return true
    else
      @original_updated_at = updated_at.to_f
      return false
    end
  end

  def recalculate
    tries = 0
    begin
      raise Product::StaleObjectError.new("StaleObjectError") if stale_object?
      attributes["updated_at"] = Time.now.utc
      Product.where(:id => self.id).update_all(attributes)
      self.attributes = attributes
    rescue Product::StaleObjectError => e
      if tries < MAX_RETRIES
        tries += 1
        sleep(1 + tries)
        reload
        retry
      else
        raise Product::StaleObjectError("StaleObjectError")
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using Rails? Not sure why you are trying to roll your own solution.
Just add a `lock_version` column to enable optimistic locking on DB level.

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Optimistic.html

Also: since you are talking about multiple machines, concurrency could come from multiple processes and multiple threads as well.

Since your legacy system breaks when adding the lock column some other solutions:

0. Fix the issues with optimistic locking
1. use pessimistic locking. Depending on the load scenario - how many concurrent read/write - operations this might work as well
2. Fix your locking code (not entirely sure how it works because you are leaving out some details of the class in question)

- no need to raise, catch and re-raise (just use a loop and `break`on success)
- you are calling `to_f` on floats
- I don't know what `self.attributes = attributes` is supposed to do (from the code you show it is unclear if `attributes` is something else than `self.attributes`)
- using a timestamp might or might not be good enough to determine concurrent updates (two exact same timestamps might be generated, clocks might be off on multiple machines, clock might get reset or adjusted in between)
- using `sleep` is a code smell

When you write code that is so complicated that you have to ask on the internet if it works, then you are probably going the wrong way. Fix the problems with optimistic locking instead of adding such a workaround.

Comment: due to some reason `lock_version ` is not working. So can't use it

Comment: due to what reasons? I'd suggest you fix the problem which prevents you from using a tried and tested solution instead of trying to roll your own. Or describe the constraints that lead to you rolling your own...

Comment: this legacy system. when I use 'lock_version' multiple existing test cases fails and I don't want to add an extra column in the model. Can you suggest why the current solution is not feasible.